# How can I export my Delicious bookmarks?

Tags: export, bookmarks, delicious

How can I obtain a list of all the bookmarks in my Delicious account?

That web service is so slow that it's difficult to use any more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delicious provides a tool for exporting (as well as importing) your bookmarks in a format readable (and writable - for import) by most modern browsers.

- [Export](https://secure.delicious.com/settings/bookmarks/export)
- [Import](https://secure.delicious.com/settings/bookmarks/import)

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why but I wasn't able to find that last time I looked.

Answer (score 0):

on the slowness:

Firefox has extension opening your delicious bookmarks in the sidebar. Awesome fast, same for taggin new links with a pop up window. You dont need the slow delicious webpage anymore and have the full functionality

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/delicious-bookmarks/