# Bulk export of Delicious bookmarks saved by other users based on tags

Tags: delicious, bookmarks, delicious-tags

Looking to bulk export a mammoth dump of bookmarks saved by other Delicious users. This isn't the same as [exporting your own bookmarks](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/467/how-can-i-export-my-delicious-bookmarks), which is handy in itself and unleashes to you your entire save collection.

Say one is interested in all things **bacon** and wants to save the rich history of all things tagged as such by throngs of other users, keeping a copy of this reference material before the library is burnt to the ground.

Hacking the [RSS feed only gets you 100](http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/rss/tag/bacon?count=32200) of these from a rough gauge of 32,220+ in the bank. Apparently, Delicious [don't make nice with automated extraction tools](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/deliciouss_data_policy_is_like_setting_a_museum_on.php) either.

Is there a way to snatch the whole batch of greasy bookmarks saved by other users of the service based on tags?

Answer (score 1):

Although automated extraction is blocked, you could give [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) a try. With the Selenium IDE you can just:

1. go to http://www.delicious.com/tag/bacon
2. search for links with class "taggedlink" and extract their url
3. search for link with classes "pn" and "next" and click it
4. repeat step 2 until last page

I know the answer comes late, but maybe this is useful for you.

Comment: Delicious is still around, so it's still not late

Comment: Then try the [Selenium IDE](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/1.0.10/selenium-ide-1.0.10.xpi) or use the excellent [Java API for Selenium 2](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-java-2.0b3.zip&can=2&q=)