# Take Over A Stack on Delicious

Tags: delicious

I've found an "abandoned" stack on Delicious and want to be the "owner" of it. The owner has been inactive for a long time and I would like to continue their work. Is this possible?

Comment: would you please elaborate what you mean by abandoned? Is there no owner at all or is it inactive?

Comment: @user99572isfine: inactive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there is no built-in way to contact another Delicious user, it appears that you are out of luck. There is no official way to take over another user's stack.

There are a few things you can try, though:

1. Search online for the user name. Maybe that person is active on other sites under the same name and can be contacted there.
2. Copy all the links in a stack to your own stack and continue there. A partially automated how-to has been [proposed on Webapps before](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10420/bulk-export-of-delicious-bookmarks-saved-by-other-users-based-on-tags).
3. Propose contacting users as a new feature in the [support forums](http://support.delicious.com/delicious).